# Can I hide the Xamarin.Auth NavigationBar?

Tags: c#, authentication, xamarin.forms, navigationbar, xamarin.auth

**Is there any possibility to hide the Xamarin.Auth NavigationBar ?**

I've searched the Xamarin Forum and many others but no one seems to have ever done this...

For authentication I am following the guide ["Authenticating Users with Azure Mobile Apps"](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/web-services/authentication/azure/).

This is my current code (on **Android**):

```
public async Task<bool> AuthenticateAsync ()
{
  ...
  // The authentication provider could also be Facebook, Twitter, or Microsoft
  user = await TodoItemManager.DefaultManager.CurrentClient.LoginAsync(this, MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Google);
  ...
}
```

[image]

If this is not possible ... Is there any way I could wrap the social login options myself ? (i.e web view or sth. ?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the answer is no. During login flow Xamarin Forms is using ADAL (Active Directory Authentication Library). On mobile devices it does not provide mechanisms for using username and password directly (raw) so you cannot implement authentication flow in the different way (like custom view).
You can read more below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-authentication-libraries